# Check email body using cypress mailhog

Tags: cypress, mailhog

I'm trying to check if the email body contains, for example, a username, but i get this error saying that the value is undefined

```js
it.only('User info', () => {
  const email= cy.mhGetMailsBySubject('Your account is now  confirmed')
  .mhFirst().mhGetBody().should('contain', 'Thanks for the verification')
  email.should('contain', 'username')

})
```

> its.Body
> CypressError Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.its()
> errored because your subject is: undefined. You cannot access any
> properties such as Body on a undefined value.
>
> If you expect your subject to be undefined, then add an assertion such
> as:
>
> cy.wrap(undefined).should('be.undefined')

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the return value of the command, instead chain another assertion like this:

```js
const username = 'Fred'

cy.mhGetMailsBySubject('Your account is now  confirmed')
  .mhFirst().mhGetBody()
  .should('contain', 'Thanks for the verification')
  .and('contain', username)
```

Comment: I tried but got the same error subject undefined

Comment: Definitely make that change, but looks like there's a 2nd problem. Try removing some steps until the error goes away - for example does `cy.mhGetMailsBySubject('Your account is now  confirmed')` by itself succeed?

Comment: Yes, i did one like this:
 cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetSubject()
        .should('eq', 'Your account is now confirmed')

Comment: Hum, that's tricky - you can take a look at the mail body with `cy.mhGetMailsBySubject('Your account is now  confirmed').mhGetBody().then(console.log)`. See if you get `undefined` logged to devtools.

Comment: I don't know what happened, can you tell me the difference between these two? `it.only('User info', () => {
    cy.mhGetMailsBySubject('Your account is now  confirmed')
    .mhFirst().mhGetBody()
    .should('contain', 'username')
    })` and

 `it.only('User info', () => {
    cy.mhGetMailsBySubject('Your account is now confirmed')
    .mhFirst().mhGetBody()
    .should('contain', 'username')     
    })` ? the last one works, and the first don't

Comment: nevermind, i found what is wrong, it was a blank space and i just couldn't see it, but thanks for the tip